# Modal footer cannot align with the body in Safari

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal which has a fixed footer. But it doesn't display correctly in Safari. The modal-footer does not align with the modal-body.

This is the bad display:
[image: Bad display]

Whenever I resize the browser, open inspect, or under inspection window to disable any css style, the footer will become correct. And it only happened in Safari, Chrome can display correctly.

[image: Correct display]

Comment: Can you give us some code of fiddle?

Comment: Love to help, but we need more than the two screencaps. Hit 'edit' and insert a SO:Snippet for us to look at.